# Prove that restricting a vector field $X$ over $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^1$ gives a vector field over $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I find the following problem a very interesting and very natural question to ask, but I could not prove or disprove it.

$Question$: Let $X$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R^2}$. If we restrict this vector field $X$ on $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ then it is a vector field over $S^1$.

MY attempt:

Since $X$ is a vector field over $\mathbb{R^2}$. then,

$X=a\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.

That is for any $p\in \mathbb{R^2}$,

$X(p)=a(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p +b(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p$.

Now consider the restriction map on $S^1$ that is,

$X(p)=a(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p +b(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p$ ; where $p\in S^1$

Now (let's try to) show $a(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p +b(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p\in T_pS^1 = span \{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p\}$

It implies that

$a(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p +b(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p= c(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p$

That is,

$b(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}|_p= (c(p)-a(p)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|_p$

I am not sure how to proceed any further?

Thanks for any insight!!

Comment: What happens if you (try to) restrict a concrete vector field on $\Bbb R^2$ like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to $S^1$?

Comment: @TravisWillse, then I think it will be a vector field on $S^1$

Comment: Is $\left.\frac\partial{\partial x}\right\vert_{(1, 0)}$ tangent to $S^1$ at $(1, 0)$? (Hint: Draw a picture.)

Comment: Which reference book are you using?

Comment: Are we talking about vector fields as in multivariable calculus or vector fields as sections of the tangent bundle? In the latter case, at each point the vector must be in the tangent space.

Answer (score 1):

1. The tangential space of $\mathbb{S}^1$ in $p = (x,y)$ is not $\mathrm{span}\left\{\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p\right\}$ but $\mathrm{span}\left\{y \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right|_p- x \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_p\right\}$, at least if you use the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$
2. Over every point $p$ the vectors $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p$ and $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_p$ are linearly independent, so for example the constant vectorfield $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ will not restrict to a vectorfield on $\mathbb{S}^1$ because $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{(1,0)} \notin \mathrm{span}\left\{\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{(1,0)}\right\} = T_{(1,0)} \mathbb{S}^1$.